# How to access array component and change their style in Vue?

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, vue-component

Hello fellow programmers,

i want to ask you guys if you know how i can change the style of a speific component of an Object array

The Code:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li v-for="jokes in joke" :key="jokes" :class="jokes">
        {{ jokes.title }}: <br />{{ jokes.text }} <br /><br />
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "Liste",
  props: ["joke"],
};
</script>

<style scoped>
.jokes {
  font-weight: bold;
}
</style>
```

so my goal here is to only change the jokes.title component of the jokes array into bold, not the whole jokes array content.

thanks in advance for you help guys <3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

However the answer provided by @thks173 works, I would suggest not to use html tags for styling purposes.
Also couple of notes:

1. You don't need to bind `class` attribute if you are using static classes.
2. key attribute should be unique primitive value e.g. `title` if it's unique.
3. And it's more convenient to loop over `jokes` and style particular `joke`.

My solution would be:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li v-for="joke in jokes" :key="joke.title" class="joke">
        <p class="title">{{ jokes.title }}</p>
        <p>{{ jokes.text }}</p>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "Liste",
  props: ["joke"],
};
</script>

<style scoped>
 .joke {
   margin-bottom: 10px;
  }
 .joke .title {
  font-weight: bold;
  }
</style>
```

Comment: This works like i want it to Thank You!
but i need to edit the `v-for"joke in jokes" :key="joke.title" ` into `v-for="jokes in joke" :key="jokes.title" `. (just changed the order of jokes and joke) and of course in the CSS tag :)

Answer (score 1):

How about this

```
<template>
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li v-for="jokes in joke" :key="jokes">
        <strong>{{ jokes.title }}: </strong> <br />{{ jokes.text }} <br /><br />
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "Liste",
  props: ["joke"],
};
</script>
```